# p5.js | Can you manipulate the pixels of a camera capture in real-time?

Tags: image, pixel, p5.js, video-capture

In the code below I'm trying to paint red every other pixel, coming from the camera capture

```
let capture

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 240);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
}

function draw() {
  // draw an image with the current frame coming from the camera capture
  image(capture, 0, 0, width, height)
  
  // load the pixels of the resulting image
  loadPixels()
  
  // loop through all the pixels and paint every other one red
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x*2) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y*2) {
      set(x, y, color('red'))
    }
  }
  
  updatePixels();
}
```

When I run the above code on https://editor.p5js.org/ the page crashes.

I believe the reason it crashes is because the frames coming from the video are endless and I'm trying to loop through every pixel of every new frame and the browser can't handle the computation.

Am I correct or is there something wrong with my code?

Is what I'm trying to do not possible ? That is, be able to manipulate any pixel coming  in from the camera capture in real time. Or is there a better way ?

Thank you for your help. This is my first time playing around with p5.js so an code snippet would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop you're increasing x and y time 2, but since it starts off at 0 and ends whenever it's over width or height, it creates an infinite loop. Also, you're not even changing x or y so it would stay at 0 anyways.

```
let capture

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 240);
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  frameRate(10);
}

function draw() {
  // draw an image with the current frame coming from the camera capture
  image(capture, 0, 0, width, height)
  
  loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < width; x ++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y ++) {
      set(x, y, get(x,y))
    }
  }
  
  updatePixels();
}
```